# Bloating in my 4 month kitten

Tags: cats, diseases, medicines

We recently got a new kitten. She's boisterous, very loving and gets on with our 1 year old very well! However, she's got a fair bit of bloating in her lower abdomen. She's got a ravenous appetite and diarrhea but no vomiting. The vet thinks it's worms (as did we) and we've given her a deworming tablet (albeit we had to crush it up, as she refused to take it whole!). The tablet seems to have done nothing, as she's still got diarrhea, and there's no signs of worm debris in the poo. Apart from this, she is active and seems to be in good health. Any ideas as to what the bloating could be caused by?

Answer (score 1):

I feed my [Basenji] dog a tiny amount of pure pumpkin on a daily basis. She's just over 20#, I give her about 1/2 teaspoon a day. It acts like a pre/probiotic and keeps her having "regular" bowel movements. No diarrhea. No constipation. It's safe for cats, too. But a kitten, I'd start out with maybe 1/8 teaspoon... Just make sure you are using Pure Pumpkin -- **not Pumpkin Pie Mix** as that has spices that would harm the little one.
[3 Surprising Health Benefits of Pumpkin for Dogs and Cats](http://throughadogsear.com/surprising-health-benefits-of-pumpkin-for-dogs-and-cats/)